# Passing column variables into Pandas function

Tags: pandas, function

I wrote a function that explicitly defines which rows of a particular column ('UNEXPLAINED_Sq') to sum in a Pandas df based on two other columns ('REPORTING_DATE', 'WindowEnd').

```
def sum_scores (row):

    s = row['REPORTING_DATE']
    e = row['WindowEnd']        
    s_sum = df.loc[df['REPORTING_DATE'] <= s, 'UNEXPLAINED_Sq'].sum()
    e_sum = df.loc[df['REPORTING_DATE'] < e, 'UNEXPLAINED_Sq'].sum()

    return (s_sum - e_sum)

df.loc[:, 'UNEXPLAINED_Sq_SUM'] = df.apply(sum_scores, axis=1)
```

Then I made it more generic so I could pass in a column variable to sum:

```
def sum_scores_5 (row, c_Name):

    s = row['REPORTING_DATE']
    e = row['WindowEnd']        

    s_sum = df.loc[df['REPORTING_DATE'] <= s, df[c_Name]].sum
    e_sum = df.loc[df['REPORTING_DATE'] < e, df[c_Name]].sum

    return (s_sum - e_sum)  

df.loc[:, 'UNEXPLAINED_Sq_SUM'] =df.apply(sum_scores_5, 'UNEXPLAINED_Sq', axis=1)
```

But returns: TypeError: apply() got multiple values for argument 'axis'

Then I thought I would use a lambda function for the multiple variables

```
df.loc[:, 'UNEXPLAINED_Sq_SUM'] = df.apply(lambda x: sum_scores_5(x, df['UNEXPLAINED_Sq']), axis=1)
```

But this returns 
KeyError: ('[2.01018345e+13 ...\n 1.67234745e+ 3.02534089e+14] not in index', 'occurred at index 0')​

which i think is because I'm attempting to pass the entire column in to be evaluated at each row.

Snippet of the data is listed below. How can I index the column variable to be summed?

*****Data Table*****

```
    REPORTING_DATE UNEXPLAINED_Sq  WindowEnd 
    2019-02-01     2.010183e+13    2018-08-01
    2019-02-04     6.136327e+13    2018-08-04
    2019-02-05     1.123688e+13    2018-08-05
    2019-02-06     1.253237e+12    2018-08-06
    2019-02-07     5.673673e+13    2018-08-07
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def sum_scores_5 (row, c_Name):

    s = row['REPORTING_DATE']
    e = row['WindowEnd']        

    s_sum = df.loc[df['REPORTING_DATE'] <= s, c_Name].sum()
    e_sum = df.loc[df['REPORTING_DATE'] < e, c_Name].sum()

    return (s_sum - e_sum)  

df.loc[:, 'UNEXPLAINED_Sq_SUM'] = df.apply(lambda x: sum_scores_5(x, 'UNEXPLAINED_Sq'), axis=1)
```